# Getting a ID back from a reducer in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm fairly new and trying to build a simple bookmark application with react & redux.

I can't spin my head around this problem:

A user can create **one bookmark** and add it to **multiple folders**. So I dispatch an `addMark(bookmark)` action, and after that `addMark(folder)` or `editFolder(folder)` if the folder already exists. As you can see, bookmark and folder are added via the same action, because in my state tree they are both just **marks** - distinguished by their type property.

My problem: How can I tell the folder-objects which is the new bookmark to add to folders list of bookmarks? How can I retrieve the ID of the newly created bookmark between the two dispatches?

Solutions I don't find satisfying:

1. I know how the bookmark-ID is generated in the reducer (via `Math.max` over the existing bookmark IDs), so I can reproduce the new bookmark ID between the 2 dispatches.This sounds like a bad hack.
2. Bookmarks and folders are kept in the same state-branch (same reducer), because they are both just "Marks", I could have a state-property that references the latest added bookmark, but this also sounds like a bad hack.

A little bit of source code, to understand what I have:

```
// mapping between dispatcher and props to my react view
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  saveMark: (mark) => {
    if (mark.id) {
      dispatch(editMark(mark));
    } else {
      dispatch(addMark(mark));
    }
  },
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddMark);
```

And Inside AddMark, which is the container component:

```
// save the bookmark first
this.props.saveMark({
      type: 'bookmark',
      title: this.state.title,
      url: this.state.url,
      icon: this.props.icon,
      style: this.state.style,
 });
 // now I need the bookmark ID
 folders.forEach(folder => {
    folder.children.push(bookmarkID) // <-- !!!
 });
 folders.forEach(folder => this.props.saveMark(folder));
```

I can't find a satisfying solution for this.

Comment: Why not just allow your `addMark` function to take in two variables;  folder *and bookmark*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should dispatch only one action here: `addBookmark()`, which accepts both bookmark object and folder.

Your code, which handles adding bookmark object into folder should be part of reducer.

Also, refer the [Todos example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/actions/index.js) in Redux project. It has id provided in action creation to make it possible to read it in the component. You can also use current state to compute latest id:

```
function addBookmark(bookmark, folder) {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
       const newBookmark = Object.assign({
         id: Math.max(0, ...getState().bookmarks.map(b => b.id)) + 1,
       }, bookmark);
       dispatch({
         type: 'ADD_BOOKMARK',
         bookmark: newBookmark,
         folder: folder
       });
   }
}
```

Notice that example requires [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware to dispatch those actions.

Then you can get access to bookmark with id in the folders reducer

```
function folderReducer(state = [], action) {
  if(action.type === 'ADD_BOOKMARK') {
     return state.map(folder => {
       if(folder === action.folder) {
         return Object.assign({}, folder, {children: [...folder.children, action.bookmark.id]}
       }
       return folder;
     })
  }
  //another reducer code
  return state;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, but this is what I was looking for! I wasn't aware of the second parameter (getState) to the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

Reducers are just manipulating your store's instance. You may the current snapshot of your state using [getState()](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#getState)